# How to tell if a a mouse button has been released outside the window?

Tags: winapi, user-interface, mouse

Usually, when a user holds the mouse pressed over a button, moves the mouse away from the window, and then releases it, the button can tell that the mouse has been released even though the release has actually occured outside the window.

When I inspect mouse clicks in my window, how can I imitate the same behavior?

When a mouse button being pushed down over the window I get the WM_XBUTTONDOWN message, but Windows don't treat it as if anything is logically being "clicked", so after the mouse leaves the window, no further messages will arrive at the window, which results in a "lost" WM_XBUTTONUP message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you receive the button down, you capture the mouse. That means that all the mouse events until releasing the capture will be reported to the window that captured the mouse.

See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262(VS.85).aspx). You also have a link to an example from that page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DragDetect() function.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dragdetect?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

As I managed to find out, there is no easy way to determine that the mouse was pressed outside the window. Since all input-related messages are tied to the current window thread.

But there is an alternative way not related to clicking the mouse but can play its role. You can catch the **WM_ACTIVATEAPP** message, which will just be called when you click the mouse outside the window. As it is written in the documentation, this message will be sent to the current application window that will be deactivated and the other application window on the level above that will now be activated.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-activateapp for more details.